# What happens when multiple threads ask for the same class to be loaded at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, classloader

In a multi-threaded environment, when multiple threads refer to a class at the same time, does the JVM end up loading the class multiple times?

If not, how does synchronization happen?

Comment: I don't remember the details (it is in the spec) but the class is guaranteed to be loaded exactly once. The JVM synchronizes internally.

Comment: [Multithreaded Custom Class Loaders in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/cl-mt.html)

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class will be loaded once. See [jls 12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock
>   LC. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java
>   Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is
>   then as follows:
>
> 1. Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.
>
> ...

Comment: Oracle blog talks about the synchronization process once a copy is loaded onto the main memory.
Does JVM provide sync at load level, I mean loading class from classpath ?